# Error: Trying to do i/o to a tablespace which exists without .ibd data file

Tags: exception, service, mariadb

I can't restart my mariadb server because I'm getting this error message and I ran systemctl status mariadb.service -l to see the full error message but it doesn't tell me what table and where the table can be found so I'm completely lost.

```
 mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─limits.conf, migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2017-04-06 10:55:41 EDT; 4s ago
  Process: 2324 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
  Process: 2202 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2199 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2324 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Status: "InnoDB: Error: Trying to do i/o to a tablespace which exists without .ibd data file. i/o type 10, space id 840720, page no 0, i/o length 16384 bytes"
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service

Apr 06 10:55:41 www.ooples.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Apr 06 10:55:41 www.ooples.com systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Apr 06 10:55:41 www.ooples.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by an orphaned idb file in the /var/lib/mysql/database_name folder and I deleted the ibd file and I was able to start the mysql server

Comment: Hi,

I am using mariadb as well inside docker, can you help how exactly you solved this issue?